# Determine $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan({\sqrt{n+1}}) - \arctan({\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

> Determine $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan({\sqrt{n+1}}) - \arctan({\sqrt{n}})$ if it exists.

I know that it exists, but I do not know how to show it. I tried to use the series definition $$\arctan (x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1},$$ but I realised that we have only defined it that way for $x \in [-1, \, 1]$ shortly after.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\text{arctan}$ function is the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) of $$\tan:\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)\rightarrow\Bbb R$$
as this function is monotonically increasing, we have
$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi 2}\tan x=+\infty\iff \lim_{x\to+\infty}\arctan x=\frac\pi2$$
therefore
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan({\sqrt{n+1}})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan({\sqrt{n}})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
so the difference is $0$.

Comment: That made it very clear, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Note,

$$\arctan{\sqrt{n+1}} - \arctan{\sqrt{n}}
=\arctan \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n+1}\cdot\sqrt{n}} $$
$$=\arctan  \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{n^2+n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} $$

Thus,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan({\sqrt{n+1}}) - \arctan({\sqrt{n}})$$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\arctan\frac1{(1+\sqrt{n^2+n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=\arctan(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a way forward that relies on an integral representation of the arctangent function along with straightforward bounds of the ensuing integral.  To that end we proceed.**

---

Define the arctangent function by the integral

$$\arctan(t)=\int_0^t \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx\tag1$$

Using $(1)$, we can write the term of interest as

$$\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})-\arctan(\sqrt n)=\int_\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n+1} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx\tag2$$

Noting that $0<\frac{1}{1+x^2}\le \frac1{n+1}$ for $x\in[\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n+1}]$, we assert from $(2)$ that

$$0<\int_\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n+1} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx\le \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+n}\tag3$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem to $(3)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})-\arctan(\sqrt n)\right)=0$$

And we are done!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late answer but I was just wondering that no solution used the MVT. So, I add this here using

- $(\arctan \sqrt{x})' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+x)}$

According to MVT there is $\xi_n \in (n,n+1)$ such that

$$\arctan({\sqrt{n+1}}) - \arctan({\sqrt{n}})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi_n}(1+\xi_n)}$$

Hence,

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}(1+(n+1))}}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}0} < \arctan({\sqrt{n+1}}) - \arctan({\sqrt{n}}) < \underbrace{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}(1+n)}}_{\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\rightarrow}0}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(\sqrt{n})=\arctan(+\infty)=\pi/2$ and, analogously, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})=\pi/2$.

So your limit is $0$.

Comment: Thank you but showing that $\arctan (+\infty) = \pi/2$ is more or less the whole problem for me.

Comment: $\arctan$ is the inverse function of $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-} \tan x=\frac{1}{0^+}=+\infty$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan (\tan [\arctan \sqrt{n+1} -\arctan √n]\big )=$

$\arctan \big (\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-√n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}√n}\big );$

$0< f(n):=\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-√n}{1+\sqrt{n+1}√n}<$

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-√n}{\sqrt{n+1}√n}=$

$(n+1)^{-1/2}-n^{-1/2};$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n)=0.$

Note $\arctan$ is continuous.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \arctan (f(n))=0$.

Answer (score -2):

Why did you go in for a round about series option?

When $n$ is large $ \sqrt {n+1}\rightarrow \sqrt{ n} $ and limit is directly seen zero as difference of two equal terms. Arctan tends asymptotically to $\pi/4$ for large arguments without monotonic increase.

Comment: So, $e^{n+1}-e^n\to0$?

Comment: Sorry, missed typing radical sign.

Comment: Take $f(x)=e^{x^2}$. Is $f(\sqrt{n+1})-f(\sqrt{n})\to0$?

Comment: Got the point. My typing error.